# When to Unit Test and When to Integration Test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, integration-testing

I am new to testing in general and am working on a Grails application.

I want to write a test that says "when this action is called, the correct view is returned". I don't know how to go about deciding if I should make something like this a unit test or an integration test. Either test would show me what I want - how do I decide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem with integration tests is their speed. For me, integration tests take 15+ seconds to start up. In that time, certain things do slip out of mind focus.

I prefer to go with unit tests that start in no more then 2 sec and can be run several times in those 15 seconds. Especially with `mockDomain().` Especially with [Grails 2.0 implementing criteria and named queries in unit tests](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.M2/guide/introduction.html#testingFeatures).

One more argument for unit tests is they force you to decouple your code. Integration tests always tempt you to just rely on some other component existing and initialized.

Comment: I favor unit tests for the majority of coverage. But sometimes I miss things with unit tests, and sometimes my assumptions about how a bit of code interacts with collaborators is wrong. So I like to also add simple integration tests to make sure collaborators play nicely together.

Comment: Well, I didn't say NOT to use integration tests; we need to test integration. But for any specific component, please do unit test it.

Answer (score 4):

[From Grails Docs section 9.1](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing)

> Unit testing are tests at the "unit" level. In other words you are
>   testing individual methods or blocks of code without considering for
>   surrounding infrastructure. In Grails you need to be particularity
>   aware of the difference between unit and integration tests because in
>   unit tests Grails does not inject any of the dynamic methods present
>   during integration tests and at runtime.

[From Grails Docs section 9.2](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html#9.2%20Integration%20Testing)

> Integration tests differ from unit tests in that you have full access
>   to the Grails environment within the test. Grails will use an
>   in-memory HSQLDB database for integration tests and clear out all the
>   data from the database in between each test.

What this means is that a unit test is completely isolated from the Grails environment whereas an integration test is not.  According to [Scott Davis](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails10148/index.html#author1), author of [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails10148/index.html), it is acceptable to write only integration tests...

> **Unit vs. integration tests**
>
> As I mentioned earlier, Grails supports two basic types of tests: unit
>   and integration. There's no syntactical difference between the two —
>   both are written as a GroovyTestCase using the same assertions. The
>   difference is the semantics. A unit test is meant to test the class in
>   isolation, whereas the integration test allows you to test the class
>   in a full, running environment.
>
> Quite frankly, if you want to write all of your Grails tests as
>   integration tests, that's just fine with me. All of the Grails
>   create-* commands generate corresponding integration tests, so most
>   folks simply use what is already there. As you'll see in just a
>   moment, most of the things you want to test require the full
>   environment to be up and running anyway, so integration tests are a
>   pretty good default. If you have noncore Grails classes that you'd
>   like to test, unit tests are perfectly fine.

Comment: I saw both of these articles. I didn't find it compelling that he said "it is fine with me". I am looking for a strong reason why I would choose one method of testing or the other for the particular test I outlined.

Comment: I kind of felt the same way about him saying "it is fine with me", but his bio is fairly impressive.  I have one of his books (Groovy Recipes) and it seems to me he usually knows what he is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First go through this chapter of the grails guide http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html

It talks about testing controllers and ability to get controller response like so :
controller.response.contentAsString

Now deciding on which test is more of an art rather than science. I prefer unit tests cause they are faster to run :)

Comment: I've read through that multiple times and saw the controller example. It is the art part that worries me. I don't have a compelling reason to choose one method or the other in my case.

Comment: Bottom line is you need both.  I use unit tests to get as much code coverage as possible - this is key for dynamic language like Groovy! Integration tests will let you know if assumptions you made in unit tests while mocking your service methods hold true.

Answer (score 0):

Its a really interesting and challenging question to answer, but the truth is it really depends on what exactly you are testing.

Take the following test: "saving a book to the database". The hints are in the description. We are saying we need a book and we need a database, so in this case a unit test wont do because we need the integrated database.

My advice is write the full test description down and break it down like I did above. It will give you the hints to help you decide.

This is made easier with spock where you can use strings for test names.